# Is it possible to record latitude and longitude from google forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I want to ask when I submit forms on Google forms, whether it's possible to update latitude and longitude for that response in response spreadsheet or not. Otherwise, is there any other way to record geo-location?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, but I would try to grab the IP address of the submitter.  From there, you can geolocate on that.  It won't give you an exact location, but you'll still get a general idea of where the request came from.

Comment: If you can show Data  (Google Spreadsheet) on a Google Forms , it's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging the Latitude and Longitude of the person submitting the Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314474/logging-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-the-person-submitting-the-google-form)