# Logging the Latitude and Longitude of the person submitting the Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a simple Google Form generated through Apps Script. I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to record the `Latitude` and `Longitude` of the user who submits a Google Form. Any guidance or tips would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Forms doesn't include a way to automatically record the geolocation of the form respondent.

Related questions

- [Is it possible to record latitude and longitude from google forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24059763/1595451) (Unanswered at this time)

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms

Comment: Thought so! Couldn't find information anywhere. Thank you!